# Display icons in the right click menu

Tags: jquery, json

I have a right click menu on my page which displays the objects inside my json file. I want to display icons alongside with the items in the menu. Here is my js:

```
$(function () {
  var json_data = {};
  var $menu = $("#menu");

  jQuery.getJSON("/new_veg2.json", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    json_data = data;
    varCallBack();
  });

  function varCallBack() {
    $.each(json_data.menu, function () {
      $menu.append(
        getMenuItem(this)
      );
      getConcept();
    });
    console.log(json_data.menu);
    checkForChildren(json_data.menu);
    console.log(childLess);
  };

  var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
    var item = $("<li>")
      .append(
        $("<a>", {
          title: itemData.name,
          html: itemData.name,
          icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-search"
          }
        }));
    if (itemData.children) {
      var subList = $("<ul>");
      $.each(itemData.children, function () {
        subList.append(getMenuItem(this));
      });
      item.append(subList);
    }
    return item;
  };


  var childLess = [];
  checkForChildren = function (items) {
    //console.log(items.length, 'abc');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      //console.log('category');
      if (items[i].children)
        checkForChildren(items[i].children);
      else
        childLess.push(items[i].name);
    }
  };

  var identifiedObjectsList = [];

  var getBrowserCoord = $("#Boma").mousedown(function (e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {
      var browserCoord = {
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY
      };
      identifiedObjectsList.push(browserCoord);
      console.log(browserCoord);
      console.log(identifiedObjectsList);
    }
  });

  function getConcept() {
    $('a').click(function (jsonData) {
      var clickedItem = $(this).attr('title');
      if (childLess.indexOf(clickedItem) > -1) {
        var concept = clickedItem;
        identifiedObjectsList.push(concept);
        console.log(identifiedObjectsList);
      } else {
        var concept = undefined;
      }
      console.log(concept);
    });
  };

  $("#menu").hide()

  document.getElementById("Boma").oncontextmenu = function () {
    return false;
  }

  $("#Boma").mousedown(function (e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {
      $("#menu").css('left', e.pageX + 5);
      $("#menu").css('top', e.pageY + 5);
      $("#menu").fadeIn(100);
      $("#menu").menu();
    }
  });

  $(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.button == 0) {
      $("#menu").fadeOut(80);
    }
  });
});
```

I have added "icons: { primary: "ui-icon-search" }" when the attribute tag is being appended to the list tag, in order to try and add a search icon along with the names but it does not seem to work. I think I am missing something or maybe adding the icons altogether incorrectly. I need some help with displaying this search icon. Here is my json:

```
{
"menu": [{

        "name": "vegetation",
        "id": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "landuse",
                "id": "1.1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "forest area",
                        "id": "1.1.1",
                        "children": null
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name": "plantation",
                        "id": "1.1.2",
                        "children": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

}]
}
```

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is create the item dynamically, in that case if the html structure you are trying to achieve will give you a something different. can you give the expected html markup?

Comment: <ul id = "menu">
     <li>
    <a>name</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a>name</a>
   <ul>
               <li><a>name</a></li>
               <li><a>name</a></li>
               <li><a>name</a></li>
      <li><a>name</a></li>
      
            </ul>
     </li>
    <li><a>name</a>
   <ul>
               <li><a>name</a></li>
               <li><a>name</a></li>
      <li><a>name</a></li>
      
            </ul>
     </li>
    
  </ul>
         </li>
</ul>

Comment: Its something of this structure but now I want to add icons in it dynamically as well.

Comment: I mean the icon code e.g. if you are using font awesome it should look like so <ul id="menu"><li><a><i class='fa fa-user'></i>name</a></li>...

Comment: I haven't used any font as yet. I was just trying to get the search icon up on the menu hoping that it will display because of the jquery-ui.

Comment: use your F12 browser tool to lookup the html markup of any icon displaying in the environment already, copy the html and then you can mimic the structure in your JSON

Comment: I tried adding your example to my code but nothing seems to happen. I don't even see anything in the web console. Can you provide me with a working example using my js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write an example for font awesome..

```
$("<a>").append($("<i>", {"class":"fa fa-user"}))
```

in that case your json should look like

```
{
   "name": "forest area",
   "class":"fa fa-user",
   id": "1.1.1",
   "children": null
 },
```

note that since class is a keyword, always keep it in quotes
you can try the below for jquery ui icons

```
{
       "name": "forest area",
       "class":"ui-icon ui-icon-clock",
       id": "1.1.1",
       "children": null
}
```

Comment: How can I add a .png image (that is in my local directory) instead of this icon?

Comment: in that case you may need to write additional code to create the image and update the url, dimensions etc, and not to add it as an attribute to the <a> tag

Comment: Can you show me an example for that using any image in your computer?